# How is The polynomials of the form $a+bx^2$ closed under addition?

Tags: vector-spaces

I was surprised to see the polynomials of the form $a + bx^2$ is a vector space since I was sure it was not closed under addition. Couldn't a term in the polynomial be negative, and when adding together the term will cancel out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terms cancelling each other out do not preclude $\{a+bx^2:a,b\in\mathbb R\}$ being a vector space. It just means that the coefficient where the terms cancelled out is 0.